# how to use notification badges with onesignal?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, onesignal

I'd like to use the notification-badge-counter in ios in my ionic-app.
The notifications already work but if I add `ios_badgeType` and `ios_badgeCount` to the notificationObject, I'm getting an error (`"All included players are not subscribed"`) .

This is my notificationObject:

```
var notificationObj = {
    contents: {en: "message"},
    include_player_ids: pushIDs,
    ios_badgeType: 'increase',
    ios_badgeCount: 1
    };
```

which is posted like this:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.postNotification(notificationObj,
function(successResponse) {
    console.log("Notification Post Success:", successResponse);
},
function (failedResponse) {
    console.log("Notification Post Failed: ", failedResponse);
});
```

note: `pushIDs` is an array containing correct playerIDs.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that you must specify which users you wish to send the message to.

If you would like to send it to all subscribers, you should add `"included_segments": ["All"]` to your notification object.

Or you can read about other targeting options available through the OneSignal API [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification).

Comment: the users are specified in the "pushIDs" array. it works if i leave the badge-properties out of the notificationObj it sends them and i can receive them.

Comment: @nicfo Oh I didn't notice the include_player_ids part on first glance.

Could you double check that all of the players supplied are subscribed to notifications? This error will get returned if none of them are subscribed.

Comment: So i contacted the oneSignal support and they were able to find the mistake: `ios-badgeType` is case-sensetive, i had to change it to `"Increase"` (capital `i`). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this function is deprecated from OneSignal side and they didn't update documentation about it yet.